# How to pass selected radio button in the next window and show that as selected in WPF?

Tags: wpf, radio-button, wpfdatagrid

I have a WPF Window with a datagrid `dgSample`. it has been bound to a list lstSample like this:

```
dgSample.itemssource=lstSample;
```

this datagrid also has a radio button column wherein i select one row by clicking on the radio button, and then, i can move to the next page after i click on the next button. On the next page, there is again the same datagrid, with the same radiobutton column. What I want is, that when i reach this page, i want the radio button that was selected in the previous page to be selected here as well.
I have tried binding the radiobutton column with an `IsSelected` Property by doing:

```
IsChecked="{Binding Path IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

but this is not working.
What can I do to make it work?

**P.S.: I prefer code-behind solution than the xaml one.**

Please help !

Answer (score 1):

Your model needs to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and call

```
PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("IsSelected"))
```

to get it to update in another view.

NB: If you set

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };
```

you won't have to check for null.